# How to run an Hyper-V host on a Windows Server 2008 R2 VM on ESXi?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, esxi

I have a server with ESXi. One of the virtual Machines has a WinSrv 2008 R2 and I want to host Hyper-V on it.

First of all: is it possible? I keep being told that no, it is not, due to hardware requirements, namely hardware enabled virtualization capabilities.

Second of all: if it is possible, how can I configure my VM to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Running a VM inside a VM is usually not possible due to hardware limitations.  The exception is "pure emulation" implementation (like [Bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/)).   But even when it is possible, it is not recommended due to severe performance degradation.

Hyper-V requires a CPU that supports hardware-assisted virtualization.  Comercial hypervisors like ESXi do not emulate the CPU features that are required for Hyper-V.

Answer (score 1):

ESXi have CPU features now.

I search also how to launch an hypervisor virtualbox (with features) inside ESXi with 2k8 host.